# IBM MFP 8.0 multiple userID stick to 1 devices when use UserAuthenticationSecurityCheck

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mpf

We are using the IBM MFP 8.0 with the UserAuthenticationSecurityCheck.
We implement the createUser method as intruction:

```
@Override
protected AuthenticatedUser createUser() {
    AuthenticatedUser user = new AuthenticatedUser(userId, userId, getName());
    return user;
}
```

But, during the time we login logout with a lots of userId, I found out that multiple userIds are sticked to the device:
[Please see the screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoVNc.png)

And the problem is when we register the device with the notification and push to the userId, it will put to the wrong one.

Anyone has experiences for this case please help?
Thanks

Comment: did you found any solution for this case ?

Answer (score 0):

After investigate, I believe that each time I uninstall the app and re-install again, pass the login step and it will create one more mapping userId - deviceId in the Devices page on MFP Application Console.

Is there anyone faced this issue?